# Ubuntu install error

Tags: installation, 12.04, cpu

I get the following error when installing ubuntu 12.04:

```
*Stooping CPU interrupts balancing deamon ..............................   [OK]
```

This is printed on black screen.

I get this when I want to move from step 8 to step 9 of this [guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop).

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's a weird problem (likely a bug) in Ubiquity which crashes it on certain computers if they are connected to any network during installation, try to run installer again without having connected to any network, and see if it works then.

Comment: Sorry, It did not work!Please help!! :D

Answer (score 0):

could you please include more information on your computer, previous operating system, and your selections (minus username and password). You can  also install Ubuntu through update manger.

Comment: Plz use the answer box just for posting answers . for trivial suggestions like yours plz posts it under the answer as a comment.

Comment: My System: OS - Windows Xp Pro SP3, Ram - 512mb, CPU - 1.59 GHz AMD Sempron 2300+